# Are there any examples of localized micro-conflicts in Mexican history?

Tags: mexico

Are there any examples of localized micro-conflicts in Mexican history that led to small-scale wars and intervention from federal forces to stop it?

To get a better idea of what I am talking about, I will provide examples of localized conflicts in American history. One example is the Lincoln County War of 1878, where competing business interests in Lincoln County, New Mexico decided to use partisan violence to suppress the activities of their rivals, culminating in the Battle of Lincoln. Federal troops intervened to stop the fighting. Another such conflict occurred in Johnson County, Wyoming, where a large-scale cattle grazing interest tried to muscle out the smaller ranchers in the county, leading to two ranch sieges before the US 6th Cavalry intervened to stop the violence.

Were there similar examples of localized micro-conflicts escalating to open warfare in Mexican history?

Comment: See the "See Also" list here for some likely candidates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_Indian_Wars

Comment: What is "open warfare"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caste_War_of_Yucat%C3%A1n

Answer (score 1):

One example I have found is the El Paso Salt war of 1877, in the Fort Worth area of Texas. That area has extensive salt lakes, which the local Mexican Americans used to extract and either sell in Mexico or use for private purposes. Mexican-Americans who settled the area would take from the salt lakes as they needed, on a communal basis, since there was no sense of private land ownership around the lakes.

After the region switched to American jurisdiction following the Mexican War, English speaking settlers began discussing private ownership of lands around the lakes. This would effectively block access to the Mexican-Amercians who were using the lake's resources on a communal basis.

By the 1870's, the issue began to boil over into an ethnically charged dispute about land ownership concepts. Partisan violence between the between those with private and communal land holding beliefs began to escalate. This ultimately culminated in a siege of twenty Texan Rangers, who were sent to establish peace and order, in the Texas-Mexican border town of San Elizario. The Texan Rangers were overwhelmed by hundreds of Mexicans, who came over the Mexican side of the border to support the siege.

Eventually the Texan Rangers negotiated a peaceful surrender and retreat. It is interesting to note that the Texan Rangers claim this is the only time they have retreated from a battlefield. Next, the US Ninth Cavalry stepped in to establish order. They were unofficially supported by New Mexican posses coming in to support their fellow Texans. I must wonder if the Ninth Cavalry, who were predominantly African American, had to step in to restrain the hostilities of the New Mexican posses as well? The residents of San Elizario were punished by losing county seat status.

I am sure there were many other micro conflicts within Mexico itself, not just along the border.

Research based on wikipedia and other internet sources.

Brian Ghilliotti

Comment: This happened no where near Fort Worth Texas.  This happened in far west Texas near El Paso and the Guadalupe mountains.  Also the Texas Rangers basically waged a war against the Mexican peoples of Texas for a hundred years. Border communities still fear the Rangers to this day.

Comment: Great answer. A supporting source would make it better.

Comment: You seem to be glassing over the execution and murder of several Americans by the mob *after* the negotiated *peaceful* surrender.

Comment: My research was primarily based on Wikipedia. My Wikipedia source does not mention this post siege massacre of those supporting land pritization. Please expand.                                                     This point brings up an interesting issue; my critics on other forums like to say "shut up and go to Wikipedia!", but your comment shows some of the limitations and biases of Wikipedia. Wikipedia just mentions that "12 people were killed and 50 wounded"' with nothing to directly suggest (in my opinion) that this was some sort of post siege massacre. This why I use these forums.